# Unable to make Ajax call in Symfony

Tags: json, ajax, symfony

I want to handle user registration via ajax call. So therefore I've created a registration class (defined as a service) which will be loaded in different controllers:

```
   public function loadRegisterForm($request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class, $user, array('attr' => array('class' => 'ajaxRegisterForm',)));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $errors = "";

        $parametersArray['result'] = "";

        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                    ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
                $user->setPassword($password);

                $user->setIsActive(1);
                $user->setLastname('none');

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();


                $parametersArray['result'] = new JsonResponse(
                    array(
                        'message' => 'Success! User registered!',
                        'result'  => $this->renderView('ImmoBundle::security/successlogin.html.twig')
                    ), 400);
            }
            else
            {
                $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($form);

                $parametersArray['result'] = new JsonResponse(
                    array(
                        'message' => 'Failure! User not registered!',
                        'result'  => $this->renderView('ImmoBundle::security/successlogin.html.twig'),
                        'errors'  => $errors,
                    ), 200);
            }
        }

        $parametersArray['register_form'] = $form;
        $parametersArray['errors'] = $errors;

        return $parametersArray;
    }
```

Then I've created a main controller, where registration form is being loaded:

```
    /*
     * @Route("/", name="MainPageNotPaginated")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        /**
         * Load register form
         */
        $registerForm = $this->get('register_form_service');
        $registerFormParameters = $registerForm->loadRegisterForm($request);

        return $this->render(
            'ImmoBundle::Pages/mainPage.html.twig',
            array(
                'register_form'  => $registerFormParameters['register_form']->createView(),
                'errors'         => $registerFormParameters['errors'],
                'result'         => $registerFormParameters['result'],
                )
        );
    }
```

Further I've added an ajax call to my javascript file:

```
$('.registerFormContainer').on('submit', '.ajaxRegisterForm', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (typeof data.message !== 'undefined') {
                    $('.registerFormContainer').html(data.result);
                }
                alert('success');
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON !== 'undefined') {
                    $('.registerFormError').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.result);
                } else {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            });
    });
```

Now, when I submit the registration form without filling in data (which normally should return an error) I've got an 'success' alert. The same 'success' alert is visible when the submitted registration form is valid.

I've tried

> console.log(data.message)

but console says 'undefined'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you add validation for the entity field?

Comment: @RedwanAbbs yes I do. But I don't think that the validation is the issue here, because if I fill all the fields and submit the form, I get the same alert 'success' window (this 'success' message comes from the line alert('success') in js file). But the data will be well inserted into the database. I think that I'm returning json object the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. I've just added this line to my main controller (not the service one):

```
if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {
    return $registerFormParameters['result'];
}
```